# How to bypass proxy for JMeter recording?

Tags: jmeter

I am not able to record the JMeter script because the Organization's proxy settings in the browsers blocking the JMeter to record the network calls. I am not allowed to change the Organizations default proxy settings in the browsers.

How can I bypass this proxy settings and record the JMeter script?

Also when I manually add the API calls in the JMeter and execute, it gives me the response of Organizations default proxy html message page. I added the Organizations proxy details in the Http request Proxy Server tab which is also failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a browser which have its own proxy configuration like [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), a fresh installation should not be impacted with your organization policies. Alternatively if you're allowed to install browser extensions you can use i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en). And finally it's possible to export recorded requests from the "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in form of [.HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) and convert this file into a JMeter test script using [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)
2. In order to replay the requests via proxy you need to configure JMeter to use this proxy, see [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) for detailed instructions, the easiest way is providing proxy details via [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password
   ```

Comment: Nice suggestions.

I have a comment about the option with saving .har file and then converting to jmx. This seemed quite easy until discovered that for some websites there are so many entries in har and so hard to 'filter' all the media from them that... it is not worth the time. Again, this observation is for websites with lots of images, media files etc.